# how to use imask react dynamic mask?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, imaskjs

I'm trying to use these two masks according to the number of digits. Visually it works, but when I send the form, the first mask is always selected. How to solve this? I'm using imask-react

```
const maskOptions = {
    mask: [
      {
        mask: '(00) 0000-0000',
        overwrite: true,
      },
      {
        mask: '(00) 00000-0000',
        overwrite: true,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the first mask is always selected"_? Aren't you retrieving the value on the `IMaskInput` directly? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the dispatch function

```
{
    mask: [{ mask: "(00) 0000-0000" }, { mask: "(00) 0 0000-0000" }],
    dispatch: (appended, dynamicMasked) => {
      const number = (dynamicMasked.value + appended).replace(/\D/g, "");

      if (number.length > 10) {
        return dynamicMasked.compiledMasks[1];
      }

      return dynamicMasked.compiledMasks[0];
    },
  }
```